# How to apply conditional style to subdataset in jasper report?

Tags: jasper-reports

My report is working fine. But I want one modification: based on some condition, the background color of the table row should be changed.

Now, as we know that table component is using its separate dataset (in my case). And I know that the thing which I want is Conditional Style but I am confused about how one can apply conditional style to subdataset or on the subdataset's field?

I can use conditional style like this:

```
<style name="BackgroundStyle" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">

<conditionalStyle>
<conditionExpression><![CDATA[Boolean.valueOf($F{}.intValue() % 2 == 0)]]></conditionExpression>
    <style backcolor="#CCFFCC"/>
</conditionalStyle>
</style>
```

How do I link to subdataset field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Jaspersoft studio, double click table component. After that the outline will show you Styles and dataset for the table component. You can add new style or change existing. Right click on `Table_TD` and choose `Create Conditional Style` and enter expression in style properties (you'll be able to chose subdataset fields).

Comment: Unfortunately I am using ireport 5.5.0 for designing purpose.

Comment: Your answer is pretty useful. I wish I was using Jaspersoft Studio, but do you know something like this about i-report?

Comment: It should work the same. Add new conditional style add write the field name from subdataset (you can't choose it from the list). I've opend the report created in Studio in iReport 5.1.0 and it worked the same as in Studio. Table styles are shown together with main report styles and there is also no difference in XML source between the styles...

Answer (score 0):

Yes this true that you can not see fields of dataset when you try to apply conditional style but don't worry about that, you can use any field in conditional style jasper will identify automatically.